# Convert.ToInt32(String) in C# not working?

Tags: c#, string, int, type-conversion

I have a text box named `textBox1`, and In a certain case, I want to convert the string in the textbox to an integer for later use as an integer.

It's throwing an error that I can't even understand. Here is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxZa0.png]

(Per Request) The code is:

```
this.textBox1.Text = string.Concat(Int.Where(c => Char.IsNumber(c)));
this.textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
```

I would really appreciate it if you could give me an answer or fix to my code, and explain why it doesn't/does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32` will, by design, return an integer, not a string.

If you're just storing the result back into the text box, there's no reason at all to convert it to a number only to convert it back to a string.

This would really only be useful if you wanted to do:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
```

That being said, you might want to use `Int32.TryParse` instead.  This allows you to check for formatting errors instead of having exceptions raised if the user types inappropriate values.

Comment: Ahh I see my error. I was trying to set a string to an integer. It doesn't matter what the result was outputted to, it just needed to be converted.

Also, how would I use `Int32.TryParse`? Just use a try-catch method?

Comment: To use Int32.TryParse you can do something like this
`int i;
Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text,i);`
I will be set to the textBox1.Text as an int if it works.